# Where are my nginx modules?

Tags: rhel, nginx, amazon-linux

I'm running the latest Amazon AMI (amzn-ami-hvm-2016.09.1.20170119-x86_64-gp2). If I run `nginx -V`, I can see it's been configured with many modules:

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
built by gcc 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) 
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-google_perftools_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt=' -Wl,-E'
```

However, `/usr/lib64/nginx/modules` is empty. Where are these modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your modules are compiled into the Nginx binary, this improves performance and most distributions deploy Nginx like this. If you want it modular you will need to [compile it yourself](https://www.nginx.com/blog/compiling-dynamic-modules-nginx-plus/).